# Qt QTcpServer high amount of concurrent connections

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I am looking around for the most suitable way to let Qt QTcpServer/QTcpSocket handle a large amount of connections (5000+)

When looking for online examples of multi-threaded servers in Qt most of them spawn a new thread for every incoming connection. However having 5000+ threads running seems like a bad idea to me.

Can someone point me into the right direction to achieve this by using the Qt Framework.

The connections will be HTTP and WebSocktets. So it will be both non-persistent and persistent connections.

Comment: Well I do not think you can have 5000+ connection in one thread, if you do not want to have one connection per thread (and I agreed) then you must have a pool connections per Thread. But do not forget that nowadays you can also have virtual machines and a virtual IP with a load balancer routing traffic on several virtual machines.

Comment: Depending on whether connections are persistent (eg. IRC) or short-lived (eg. HTTP), different techniques may be used. What kind of connections are you going to handle?

Comment: You could use a QThreadPool for this (or create your own threadpool)

Comment: You should probably create a single-threaded version first. See how much latency in data handling that gives you. Then add handing established connections over to worker thteads, with better understanding of what exactly you need.

Comment: Added more information about the kind of connections